# asp.net transactions error, communication error in the underlying transaction manager

Tags: asp.net, sql, transactions, webforms, ironpython

Im using webforms and I need to define a transaction. Im using the System.EnterpriseServices namespace. I have Transaction="RequiresNew" at the top of the page and Im defining the transaction like this

```
conn.open()
try:
   cmd.executenonquery()
   ContextUtil.SetComplete()
exception:
   ContextUtil.SetAbort()
finally:
   conn.Close()
```

The problem is I also have before another call to a library with another conection to the database in the same page, I dont need this other operation to run in a transaction, and this call is triggering the following error (sort of, translated from spanish)

communication error in the underlying transaction manager. 
(Error de comunicación con el administrador de transacciones subyacente.)

```
def dosomething( parameters ):
   conn.open()
   reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
   # do something
   reader.Close()
   conn.Close()
```

Comment: I take it that the MSDTC service is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the MSDTC service is disabled